# Leer un solo caracter en C

Tags: c, algoritmos

Estaba haciendo un menú de opciones y me encontré con un problema.

Cuando pongo "a" y presiono enter voy a la opción a pero si pongo "a3214" tambien me lleva a la opcion a. Mi pregunta es si puedo evitar eso y que muestre un mensaje de error si no es solamente la opción a la que escribo

```
int main()
{
    char option;

    printf("Write a single character\n");
    do
        option=getchar();
    while(option!='a' && option!='b'&& option!='c' );

    switch(option)
    {
        case 'a': printf("Hello\n");
        break; 
        case 'b': printf("How are you\n");
        break;
        case 'c': printf("Bye\n");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Venga, un voto. Supongo que sera una práctica sobre bucles.

Comment: OT: `getchar` devuelve `int` en vez de `char`

Comment: La función que devuelve un carácter sin esperar al intro se llama `getch`. La mala noticia es que está incluida en librerías que no son estándar. Concretamente en `<ncurses.h>` en sistemas unix y `<conio.h>` en windows.

Comment: Ya actualizé la pregunta, me había expresado mal. Quiero evitar que cuando que cuando ingrese una opcion seguido de cualquier cosa "a121" , me lo tome bien y entre en el switch ,sino que muestre un mensaje de error que solo habia que poner 1 caracter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución más limpia es usar `fgets`, `fgets` permite almacenar en un buffer lo que escribimos en `stdin`, solo tienes que comprobar que el primer carácter sea `a`, `b` o `c` y que el segundo carácter sea un intro (`'\n'`), de esta forma te aseguras de que el usuario no ha escrito algo erróneo como `"a3214"`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[128];
    char option;

    printf("Write a single character\n");
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        option = buf[0];
        if (option == 'a' || option == 'b' || option == 'c' ) {
            if (buf[1] == '\n') break;
        }
        puts("Introduzca un solo carácter: [a b c] seguido de un intro.");
    }   
    switch(option)
    {
        case 'a': printf("Hello\n");
        break; 
        case 'b': printf("How are you\n");
        break;
        case 'c': printf("Bye\n");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Otro detalle importante a tener en cuenta es que siempre conviene inicializar las variables. En este caso concreto no está garantizado que `fgets` se ejecute con éxito (puedes comprobarlo lanzando el programa con `cat archivo_vacio | ./programa`), más adelante, al leer la variable sin inicializar `option` en `switch(option)` estaremos accediendo a algún sector conteniendo "basura", en este instante el comportamiento del programa es impredecible, para curarte en salud:

```
    char option = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu código no tiene sentido:

`getchar( )` -> lee **1** y solo uno, por muchos mas que pulses.

`while( ... )` -> supongo que quieres esperar hasta que se pulse un carácter correcto, pero, como has dejado el `getchar( )` fuera del bucle, o bien entra en un bucle infinito, o bién no hace nada ( si el caracter es 'a', 'b', o 'c' ).

`switch( ) { ... }` -> Es lo único que parece estar bien.

Ya tienes suficientes pistas para ir tirando ...

**EDITO**

Me avergüenza reconocer que no vi el `do`. Me estaré haciendo viejo.

Teniendo ese `do` en cuenta, la cosa cambia bastante. Ahora si le veo yo sentido a esto, y a tu pregunta, si la he entendido bien.

¿ Quieres que te reconozca la pulsación de la 1ª tecla, sin tener que pulsar ENTER ?

Respuesta corta, para variar: **no puedes**. Las funciones de I/O *esperan* hasta que pulses ENTER. No hay nada que hacer (en Linux, podrias poner el terminal en modo *raw*, pero eso es otra historia ).

**EDITO 2**

Con la nueva explicación del usuario, la cosa ha quedado mas clara. Lo que quieres hacer es leer una cadena y, si tiene **mas de 1 caracter**, indicar el error.

1. No puedes usar usar `getchar`. Usa `fgets` o `scanf`.
2. Uses la que uses, necesitaras un *buffer* para almacenar la cadena. Hay
   *tropecientas* preguntas sobre arreglos y arrays en este sitio,
   cualquiera te puede servir.
3. Tienes que obtener la longitud de la cadena leída. Si la longitud es `> 1`, es un error del usuario y tratarlo como tal.
4. En otro caso, comprobar el **primer** caracter de la cadena.

Comment: Disculpa, ¿como que getchar() está fuera del bucle?. Está dentro de un do/while, recien lo probé en gcc y compila sin bucle infinito.

Comment: Llevas razón, no vi el `do`. Editaré esa parte.

Comment: No me expliqué bien, cuando pongo "a" y presiono enter voy a la opcion a
pero si pongo "a3214" tambien me lleva a la opcion a. Mi pregunta es si puedo evitar eso y que muestre un mensaje de error si no es solamente la opcion a la que escribo

Comment: Edita la pregunta, por esa explicación que me has dado ahora, y veremos si se puede hacer algo. Vamos, poder se puede, cambiando `getchar` por otra.