# ¿Cómo puedo verificar los datos de un arreglo con los datos que se le piden al usuario?

Tags: array, c, matriz, datos, imprimir

**soy nuevo en esto y solo tengo la parte para imprimir el arreglo
la idea es que cuando se imprima el arreglo, se le pida al usuario dato por dato para ir
comparando con los datos que aparecen en el arreglo, pero sin dar enter    **

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 23

int main(){

char nombres[5][MAX] = {"marcos rodriguez bosca",
                       "jose fernando rios",
                       "maria jose gonzalez",
                       "francisca gil gomez",
                       "alberto rueda galeano"};
                       
for(int i = 0; i < 5;i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < MAX; j++){
        printf("%c",nombres[i][j]);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Pues tendrás que leer carácter a carácter de la consola y si es espacio en blanco comparar

Comment: Mira esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33410/leer-un-solo-caracter-en-c

Comment: Con la librería estándar de C **no se puede hacer**. La IO estándar no devuelve el control al programa hasta que no se pulsa el enter

Comment: usar getch() de windows.h

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar se me ocurre algo usando *getch()* de la biblioteca *<conio.h>* así:

```
int Pregunta(char cNombres[5][MAX])
{
    int chars;
    int pos = 0;
    int listafiltra[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int ret = 0;
    // mostramos primero todos los nombres
    ret = coincidencias(listafiltra, cNombres);

    printf("Finaliza cada cadena con un punto: \n");

    while (((chars = getch()) != '.') && (ret > 0))
    {
        if (filtrar(chars, pos++, listafiltra, cNombres))
            break;
        ret = coincidencias(listafiltra, cNombres);
    }
    // devolvemos el numero de coincidencias
    return ret;
}
```

- listafiltara: cadenas que coinciden con la entrada
- filtrar: elimina de la lista y devuelve true si no existen
  coincidencias
- coincidencias:muestra la lista con las cadenas

**Faltaría implementar estas ultimas funciones**

```
int filtrar(int c, int p, int listafiltra[5], char cNombres[5][MAX])
{
    int ret = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (listafiltra[i] >= 0)
        {
            if (c != cNombres[i][p])
            {
                listafiltra[i] = -1;
                ret--;
            }
        }
        else
            ret--;
    }
    return ret == 0;
}
```

Y por ultimo:

```
int coincidencias(int listafiltra[5], char cNombres[5][MAX])
{
    int ret = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (listafiltra[i] >= 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
            {
                putch(cNombres[i][j]);
            }
            putch(' ');
        }
        else
            ret--;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return ret;
}
```